# 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, automapper

```
_quatationRepository = new QuatationRepository();
IList<Quatation> quatationObj = _quatationRepository.GetAll(quatation => quatation.IsDeleted == 0);
IList<QuatationModel> quatationModelObj = new List<QuatationModel>();

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Quatation, QuatationModel>();
quatationModelObj = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(quatationObj, quatationModelObj);
return quatationModelObj;
```

---

```
public partial class Quatation
{
    public int QuatationId { get; set; } 
    public int FirmId { get; set; } 
    public int ItemId { get; set; } 
    public double Quantity { get; set; } 
    public decimal Price { get; set; } 
    public Nullable Dated { get; set; } 
    public Nullable IsDeleted { get; set; } 
    public Nullable CreatedDate { get; set; } 
    public Nullable CreatedBy { get; set; } 
    public Nullable ModifyDate { get; set; } 
    public Nullable ModifyBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Firm Firm { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class QuatationModel
{
    public int QuatationId { get; set; } 
    public int? FirmId { get; set; } 
    public int ItemId { get; set; } 
    public double Quantity { get; set; } 
    public decimal Price { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? Dated { get; set; } 
    public int IsDeleted { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; } 
    public int? CreatedBy { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; } 
    public int? ModifyBy { get; set; }

    //public string ItemName { get; set; }
    //public List<SelectListItem> LstFirm { get; set; }


    public virtual FirmModel Firm { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemModel Item { get; set; }
    //public IList<QuatationModel> LstQuatation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your Quatation and QuatationModel class properties ?

Comment: Can You Please check it and provide me the answer as soon as possible ..Its urgent Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you try it out and let me know if it worked?

Comment: Well, *that's* urgent @Seany84 :)

Comment: Haha yeah, I was just sitting around twiddling my thumbs with nothing to do :) @GertArnold

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that properties with the same name have the same type. For example int on one side and Nullable on the other side will not work (IsDeleted).

Comment: You need to fix the types of all the properties (those found in both classes with the same name that is) to match in both classes not just the example I gave.  If you have fixed those types then please post the new classes

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your Nullable properties on the Quatation class to :

```
public partial class Quatation
{
    public int QuatationId { get; set; } 
    public int FirmId { get; set; } 
    public int ItemId { get; set; } 
    public double Quantity { get; set; } 
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Dated { get; set; }
    public int IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }
    public int? ModifyBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Firm Firm { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

and then try to map i.e.

```
_quatationRepository = new QuatationRepository();
IList<Quatation> quatationObj = _quatationRepository.GetAll(quatation => quatation.IsDeleted == 0);
IList<QuatationModel> quatationModelObj = new List<QuatationModel>();

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IList<Quatation>, IList<QuatationModel>>();
quatationModelObj = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IList<Quatation>, IList<QuatationModel>>(quatationObj.ToList());
return quatationModelObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply 
actually error occurred due to my relationship with another table.
i just remove remove foreign keys and update my edmx file.
then error is resolved .

its due to inconsistent data in all related tables.

Thanks for reply again .